# Since when are multiline code comments supported?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, code-formatting

I have noticed a few comments today that include multiline comment formatting (for example on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21984514/1048572)), and wondered when this was enabled and where this was announced.

I've searched a bit on meta, but feature-requests like [Add syntax highlighting and line breaks to comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4481/183280) still have status: declined. Neither the [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/183280) FAQ nor the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) mention this.

Also, how does it work? As suggested in the comments: Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you link to an example comment?  As it is, it's not quite clear what you're referring to.

Comment: @hichris123: No, like this: `do
something with
    very fancy
indentation` (inline block?)

Comment: `sealed class QueryProcessor : IQueryProcessor
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public QueryProcessor(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }
}
`

Comment: I hope that's a bug.

Comment: Oh... this is bad. Please don't teach people how to do this. Please?

Comment: My money's on this being a bug, and that non-space whitespace in code probably should be removed from comments, and that this is an overslight.

Comment: It's taking all of my willpower not to delete those multiline comments.

Comment: [Works on Stack Overflow too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991843/how-to-add-a-constant-into-linq-query-in-bltoolkit/21992098#comment33342435_21992098)

Comment: This. Is. A. New. Era.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You're totally blasting the comments section. Could you please shorten it a little bit? :-)

Comment: If you're dealing with SO newbies in [tag:python] though life just got a whole lot easier @George... where's Martijn? If he's happy then everyone should be!

Comment: This may be when it was added. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one/222376#222376

Comment: @Simon: Make that an answer!

Comment: @Bergi I want to have 1 rep for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222037/why-can-1-rep-users-comment-everywhere-on-meta

Comment: @George `Make
my
day,
Punk!`

Comment: These comments are a mess now that this has been fixed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They aren't, it was a bug. When making [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222376/), I swear did read the spec to check for side effects of the change, but somehow the phrase "Lines are broken at newline characters" was able to cross my brain unharmed.

Fixed now. Newlines, that is, not my brain.

Comment: Well, that was fun while it lasted.

Answer (score 7):

> how does it work?

This at least I figured out. Simply enter line breaks inside the comment (by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, to prevent automatically submitting the form), and use backticks for code formatting as usual:

```
My very simple sample comment `with (trivial) {
   code_formatting()
}` that is going to be indented
```

becomes

> My very simple sample comment `with (trivial) {
>       code_formatting()
>   }` that is going to be indented

Technically, the markup will preserve these whitespaces, and the CSS for this is

```
code { 
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

which also applies to the comment sections.

Comment: This is awesome! The potential for abuse is well...

Comment: Aww... Seems like it was too inappropriate even for meta... :(

Comment: `Nothing
    is too inappropriate
       for meta`

Comment: ***`THIS

IS

METAAAAAAAAAAA`***

Comment: `META?

     META?

         WE DON NEED NO STEENKING META!`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I thought so too. But my 500 newlines comment was insta-deleted. :)

Comment: @Mysticial that's because I flagged it as "too awesome." Also, the Android app doesn't show the newlines, :( `<- that's a sad face`

Comment: For anyone who wants to know what 500 newlines looks like, [Mysticial has reposted that comment in the sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment725420_3122).

Answer (score 6):

> When this was enabled and where this was announced?

As @Sinon found, it was introduced to prevent [Multiple spaces in code in comments get merged into one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one/222376#222376)

> *I've added this to our stylesheets:*
>
> ```
> code {
>     white-space: pre-wrap; /* don't collapse multiple spaces in code */
> }
> ```
>
> *– no idea why we never did that; it's an easy enough fix, and
>   these days it's supported by all browsers. This is in the next build.*

> Is this a bug?

A side effect, at least.

Comment: `+1
for
at least`